# Array of tablerows - can't give it context?

Tags: java, android, tablerow, android-context, timetable

So for my code, I'm trying to fill a timetable with data from a database. The best way for me to do this is to create a blank timetable, then fill it in afterwards. I know exactly how many rows I need, so I'm using an array of TableRows, then adding a certain amount of TextViews to each row.

However, it crashes after every run. I think it may have something to do with the tablerows not having context? Here's all the relevant code, I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

```
public class Timetable123 extends Activity {
    TableRow[] row= new TableRow[36];  //declared at start

    InitializeTable(SortedDatesList.toArray(new String[SortedDatesList.size()])); // List converted to array sent to initializeTable

}

    private void InitializeTable(String...params){


        for(int i=0;i<36;i++) {
            row[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            try {
                for (Integer j = 0; j < (params.length+1); j++) {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                    tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    row[i].addView(tv);
                    System.out.println(params[i] + " run " + i);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

It always crashes when initializeTable is called, and I really can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Array of type `TableRow` but not adding `TableRow` object before accessing `TableRow` from Array :

```
 for(int i=0;i<36;i++) {
   row[i]=new TableRow(Timetable123.this); //<< Create Object here
   row[i].setLayoutParams(new 
           TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
...
}
```

Comment: But surely if I do that then I can't reference the tablerow from anywhere else?

Comment: @user3925417: yes must add TableRow objects using `row[i]=new TableRow(Timetable123.this);` line in row Array before accessing it anywhere else